# Как получить весь список данных из всех input?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Возникла нужда подключить калькулятор калорийности на сайте, но тут возникла загвоздка, как теперь получить все данные из заполненных input одним списком. Нужно вывести все указанные ингредиенты в отдельный блок DIV, чтобы каждый ингредиент был разделен запятой.

Имеется блок куда добавляется ингредиент, в блоке 3 input, в 1-й мы вводим ингредиент "помидор", во 2-й мы указываем вес "2", а в 3-й единицу измерения "шт". Получается в итоге **"Помидор 2 шт"**.

Каждая новая строка с новыми полями для ввода сформирована таким образом:

```
<div class="form-box-cont">
    <div class="form-box-ingrid">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Название ингредиента" id="ingred2" name="ingred_group[1][ingredient][2][name]" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-box-inp">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Кол-во" name="ingred_group[1][ingredient][2][value]" value="">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Ед.Изм." id="unit2" name="ingred_group[1][ingredient][2][unit]" value="">
    </div>
</div>
```

Соответственно нужно вытащить ингредиенты в таком формате:
Допустим у нас имеется 5 ингредиентов, получаем на выходе в новом блоке "Помидор 2 шт, Огурец 1шт, Мука 200 гр, Соль по вкусу, Горошек 1 банка". Нужно чтобы весь получиный список выводился одной строкой.

Как это сделать не соображу никак? Потихоньку пытаюсь учить JS, но сложновато пока дается.

Прошу у вас помощи.

Вот код формирования списков для внесения ингредиентов:

```js
//Поля ингредиентов
function addIngredient(group, name, value, unit) {
  name = name || '';
  value = value || '';
  unit = unit || '';
  var id = ++ingredientsCount;
  var groupId = group.data('id');
  var rowCount = group.find('tr').length;
  var inputHTML = '<tr class="ingredient_box"><td>' + (rowCount < 0 ? 'Название ингредиента <span style="color:red;">*' : '') + '</td><td><div class="form-box-cont">' +
    '<div class="form-box-ingrid"><input type="text" placeholder="Название ингредиента" id="ingred' + id + '" name="ingred_group[' + groupId + '][ingredient][' + id + '][name]" value="' + name + '"></div>' +
    '<div class="form-box-inp"><input type="text" placeholder="Кол-во" name="ingred_group[' + groupId + '][ingredient][' + id + '][value]" value="' + value + '">' +
    '<input type="text" placeholder="Ед.Изм." id="unit' + id + '" name="ingred_group[' + groupId + '][ingredient][' + id + '][unit]" value="' + unit + '">' +
    '</div></div></td>' +
    (rowCount >= 2 ? '<td class="td-comment"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="inp-close" title="Удалить список">x</a>' :
      '<th class="td-comment td-comment-pad">') +
    '</tr>';
  group.find('.ingredient-cont').append(inputHTML);

}

function delIngredient() {
  $(this).parents('tr').remove();
  return false;
}

function addGroup(name) {
  name = name || '';
  groupsCount++;
  var id = groupsCount;
  var html = '<div class="group-wrap" data-id="{id}"><div class="border-header"><span>{title}</span></div> \
        <div class="form-table ingredient-cont"><div class="ingredient-cont_item"><div class="title-Group">Для чего ингредиенты <span class="td-comment">Например: <a href="javascript:void(0)">Для соуса</a></span></div><input type="text" name="ingred_group[{id}][name]" value="{name}"> \
        </div></div></div>';
  if (groupsCount == 1) {
    html = html.replace(/\{title\}/, 'Добавить ингредиент');
  } else {
    html = html.replace(/\{title\}/, 'Дополнительный список <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="close-block" title="Удалить список">x</a>');
  }
  html = html.replace(/\{id\}/g, id);
  html = html.replace(/\{name\}/g, name);
  return $(html).appendTo('.add-list-box');
}

function delGroup() {
  $(this).parents('.group-wrap').remove();
  return false;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.add-list').click(function() {
    var group = addGroup();
    addIngredient(group);
    addIngredient(group);
    return false;
  });

  $('div.ingredients')
    .on('click change', '.ingredient-cont .form-box-ingrid input', function() {
      $(this).parents('.ingredient-cont').removeClass('has-error');
      if ($(this).parents('tr').is(':last-child')) {
        addIngredient($(this).parents('.group-wrap'));
      }
      return false;
    })
    .on('click', '.inp-close', delIngredient)
    .on('click', '.close-block', delGroup);

});


var ingredientsCount = 0;
var groupsCount = 0;

if (typeof ingredientsList !== 'undefined' && ingredientsList.length) {
  groupsCount = ingredientsList.length;

  $.map(ingredientsList, function(data) {
    var group = addGroup(data['name']);

    $.map(data['ingredient'], function(ingredient) {
      addIngredient(group, ingredient['name'], ingredient['value'], ingredient['unit']);
    });

    addIngredient(group);
  });
} else {
  // ингредиенты
  if (!groupsCount) {
    var group = addGroup();
    addIngredient(group);
    addIngredient(group);
  }
}
```

```css
/* - Блок добавить ингредиенты- */

.ingredient_box {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}

.form-box.ingredients {
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px 0 20px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  border-radius: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.form-box.ingredients::after {
  z-index: -1;
  transform: scaleX(1.082);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:780px) {
  .form-box.ingredients::after {
    transform: scaleX(1.2);
  }
}

.form-box.ingredients .add-list-box .form-box-cont {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 5px 0 10px;
}

.ingredient_box td:nth-child(2),
.form-box-ingrid {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.form-box-ingrid input {
  width: 100%;
}

.form-box.ingredients .add-list-box .form-box-inp input {
  max-width: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.form-box.ingredients .add-list-box .ingredient-cont_item {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px 0 20px;
}

.form-box.ingredients .add-list-box .form-table input {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.ingredient-cont_item .title-Group {
  padding: 10px 30px 10px 0;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:480px) {
  .form-box.ingredients .add-list-box .form-box-inp input {
    width: 42%;
  }
}

.title-Group {
  padding-right: 30px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.form-box.ingredients .add-list-box .form-table .td-comment {
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-style: italic;
  color: #878787;
}

.form-box.ingredients .border-header {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #c5c5c5;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 0 25px;
}

.form-box.ingredients .border-header span {
  padding: 0 20px;
  background: #f8f8f8;
  display: inline-block;
  bottom: -13px;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.form-box.ingredients .add-list {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  color: #2a82c5;
  font-style: normal;
  height: 23px;
  line-height: 21px;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 10px 2px 26px;
  font-size: 14px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px #dadada;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px #dadada;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px #dadada;
}

.form-box.ingredients .add-list:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '+';
  top: 5px;
  left: 6px;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #2a82c5;
}

.form-box.ingredients .add-list:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #d81760;
}

.form-box.ingredients .close-block {
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 5px;
  color: red;
}

.form-box.ingredients .inp-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: -12px;
  font-style: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-box ingredients">
  <div class="add-list-box"></div>
  <div class="border-header">
    <span><a href="" class="add-list">Добавить еще список</a></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Это весь код? Я хочу рефактор нажать

Comment: Вадим, это весь код что есть.

Comment: Прошу прощения за глупый вопрос, что вы имели ввиду (нажать рефактор)? Я пока не разбираюсь во всех терминах.....

Comment: Чичас сделаю. Refactoring = ПереЗавод = Красивый чтоб был :)

Comment: немного не понимаю, что за действо должно быть в коде после `if(typeof ingredientsList`

Comment: Вадим, это я заказывал код  у одного парнишки, он сделал скорее всего связь к БД, если мне нужно будет отредактировать после новость все данные должны подтянутся по полям. Это мое предположение. Но эти строки нужны если они есть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Драфтвуйте)

```js
let ingredientsCount = 0;
let groupsCount = 0;

const addIngredient=(group, name='', value='', unit='')=>{
    const id = ingredientsCount++;
    const groupId = group.data('id');
    const rowCount = group.find('tr').length;
    const inputHTML = `<tr class="ingredient_box"><td>${rowCount < 0 ? 'Название ингредиента <span style="color:red;">*</span>' : ''}</td><td><div class="form-box-cont">
        <div class="form-box-ingrid"><input type="text" placeholder="Название ингредиента" id="ingred${id}" name="ingred_group[${groupId}][ingredient][${id}][name]" value="${name}">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Кол-во" name="ingred_group[${groupId}][ingredient][${id}][value]" value="${value}">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Ед.Изм." id="unit${id}" name="ingred_group[${groupId}][ingredient][${id}][unit]" value="${unit}"></div></div></td>
        ${rowCount >= 2 ? '<td class="td-comment"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="inp-close" title="Удалить список">x</a>' : '<th class="td-comment td-comment-pad">'}</tr>`;
    group.find('.ingredient-cont').append(inputHTML);
};

const addGroup=(name='')=>{
    groupsCount++;
    let title = 'Доп ингредиенты <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="close-block" title="Удалить список">x</a>';
    if(groupsCount === 1)title = 'Ингредиенты';
    // if(groupsCount === 1)title = 'Категория <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="close-block" title="Удалить список">x</a>';
    let id = groupsCount;
    let html = `<div class="group-wrap" data-id="${id}"><div class="border-header"><span>${title}</span></div>
        <div class="form-table ingredient-cont"><div class="ingredient-cont_item"><div class="title-Group">Для чего ингредиенты
        <span class="td-comment">Например: <a href="javascript:void(0)">Для соуса</a></span></div>
        <input type="text" name="ingred_group[${id}][name]" value="${name}"></div></div></div>`;
    return $(html).appendTo('.add-list-box');
};

window.onload=()=>{
    $('.add-list').click((e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        const group = addGroup();
        console.log('group');
        addIngredient(group);
        addIngredient(group);
    });
    
    $('div.ingredients').on('click change', '.ingredient-cont .form-box-ingrid input', ({currentTarget})=>{
        $(currentTarget).parents('.ingredient-cont').removeClass('has-error');
        if($(currentTarget).parents('tr').is(':last-child')){
            addIngredient($(currentTarget).parents('.group-wrap'));
        }
    });
    
    $('div.ingredients').on('click', '.inp-close', ({currentTarget})=>{
        $(currentTarget).parents('tr').remove();
    });
    
    $('div.ingredients').on('click', '.close-block', ({currentTarget})=>{
        $(currentTarget).parents('.group-wrap').remove();
    });
    
    // return false;
    if(typeof ingredientsList !== 'undefined' && ingredientsList.length){
        groupsCount = ingredientsList.length;
        console.log('ingredientsList');
        
        $.map(ingredientsList, (data)=>{
            let group = addGroup(data['name']);
            
            $.map(data['ingredient'], (ingredient)=>{
                addIngredient(group, ingredient['name'], ingredient['value'], ingredient['unit']);
            });
            addIngredient(group);
        });
    }else{
        if(!groupsCount){
            console.log('groupsCount');
            let group = addGroup();
            addIngredient(group);
            addIngredient(group);
        }
    }
};

const getTextsFromInput=()=>{
    let arr = [];
    $('.add-list-box').find('.form-box-ingrid').each((i, e)=>{
        if($(e).children('input:first').val() === '')return true;
        arr.push(`${$(e).children('input:nth-child(1)').val()} ${$(e).children('input:nth-child(2)').val()} ${$(e).children('input:nth-child(3)').val()}`);
    });
    return arr.join(', ');
};

$('#butn').click(()=>{
    let x = getTextsFromInput();
    console.log(x);
});
```

```css
/* - Блок добавить ингредиенты- */

.ingredient_box{
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
}

.form-box.ingredients{
    position: relative;
    margin: 50px 0 20px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    border-radius: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.form-box.ingredients::after{
    z-index: -1;
    transform: scaleX(1.082);
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:780px){
    .form-box.ingredients::after{
        transform: scaleX(1.2);
    }
}

.form-box.ingredients .add-list-box .form-box-cont{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 5px 0 10px;
}

.ingredient_box td:nth-child(2),
.form-box-ingrid{
    display: flex;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.form-box-ingrid input{
    width: 100%;
}

.form-box.ingredients .add-list-box .form-box-inp input{
    max-width: 70px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.form-box.ingredients .add-list-box .ingredient-cont_item{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 10px 0 20px;
}

.form-box.ingredients .add-list-box .form-table input{
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.ingredient-cont_item .title-Group{
    padding: 10px 30px 10px 0;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:480px){
    .form-box.ingredients .add-list-box .form-box-inp input{
        width: 42%;
    }
}

.title-Group{
    padding-right: 30px;
    line-height: 1.2;
    font-size: 13px;
}

.form-box.ingredients .add-list-box .form-table .td-comment{
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #878787;
}

.form-box.ingredients .border-header{
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #c5c5c5;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 0 25px;
}

.form-box.ingredients .border-header span{
    padding: 0 20px;
    background: #f8f8f8;
    display: inline-block;
    bottom: -13px;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.form-box.ingredients .add-list{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    color: #2a82c5;
    font-style: normal;
    height: 23px;
    line-height: 21px;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 5px 10px 2px 26px;
    font-size: 14px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px #dadada;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px #dadada;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px #dadada;
}

.form-box.ingredients .add-list:before{
    position: absolute;
    content: '+';
    top: 5px;
    left: 6px;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #2a82c5;
}

.form-box.ingredients .add-list:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #d81760;
}

.form-box.ingredients .close-block{
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 16px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 5px;
    color: red;
}

.form-box.ingredients .inp-close{
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: -12px;
    font-style: normal;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<html><head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="cssfile.css">
</head><body>
    <div class="form-box ingredients">
        <div class="add-list-box">
        </div>
        <div class="border-header">
            <span>
                <a href="" class="add-list">Добавить еще список</a>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="as-console-wrapper">
        <div class="as-console">
        </div>
    </div>
    <button id="butn" style="width:100px;height:100px;"></button>
    <script src="javascript.js"></script>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var ingredientsLst = []; // здесь будут все блоки ингредиентов
$('.form-box-cont').each(function() { // проходим по всем блокам
    var ingredientParts = [];
    $('input', this).each(function() {
        ingredientParts.push($(this).val()); // собираем все input в массив
    });
    ingredientsLst.push(ingredientParts.join(' '));
}
```